# I'm an Australian and have previously travelled to Iran; can I go to Guam without a visa?

Tags: visas, paperwork, visa-free-entry, australian-citizens, guam

I'm on an Australian passport, and I want to go to Guam for an event for about a week (pleasure, not business).  Ordinarily, I could go to Guam without a visa, but this might be complicated because:

- Having travelled to Iran for research, I'm not longer eligible for an ESTA.  While this applies to mainland US, I'm not sure of the impact on Guam.
- My travel history is complicated: I travel so much, it's no longer possible for me to list the countries I've been to in the last 10 years.  I applied to go to the US for a conference, but the process was incredibly long, and eventually had to retrieve my passport in order to go to another country.

*Question*: Can I go to Guam without a visa?

I need to pay for things in Guam, so it's best to have a good idea whether or not I can actually enter.

Comment: It might be useful to post a separate question about your lack of documents demonstrating the change in your "biographical data."  This is rather a distinct issue from your travel history, and as you see neither of the present answers addresses the first.

Comment: (Just curious and you don't have to answer, but what do you do where you get to travel that much?)

Comment: This has to be one of the most specific visa questions this site has received; I love it

Comment: I've removed the transgender aspect of your question as it made the question too broad. Please ask that part of the question separately.

Comment: FYI, for the future you may want to consider applying for a second passport. I have no experience of this in Australia, but apparently [it is available](https://www.passports.gov.au/using-your-passport/concurrent-passports).

Comment: Another thought: if you plan to go to another part of the US, you can just apply for a B visa and also use that to go to Guam.  This is less attractive for an Australian, however, because the standard $160 visa fee yields only a 1-year visa (for most countries it is a 5- or 10-year visa).  You can get a 5-year visa for $185, however.

Answer (score 19):

This is only a partial answer, but it's too long for a comment.

There is a separate [Guam-CNMI Visa Waiver Program](https://i736.cbp.dhs.gov/I736/#/home) that is open to citizens of certain countries, including Australia.  ("CNMI" stands for Commonwealth of the Northern Mariana Islands.)  There have been some [proposed changes](https://www.guampdn.com/story/news/2018/06/24/dhs-seeks-more-info-guam-cnmi-bound-tourists-visa-waivers/720641002/) to this program under which applicants for this program will be asked, among other things, about their travel to several other countries (including Iran) since 2011.  However, it does not appear that travelers who have visited these countries are completely barred from this program, as they are for the "main" Visa Waiver Program.   It is also not clear to me whether these changes have taken effect yet, or when they will take effect.

You can see a more complete list of the proposed changes in the [Federal Register.](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2018/08/21/2018-17966/agency-information-collection-activities-guam-cnmi-visa-waiver-information)

Answer (score 8):

The restriction on people having visited Iran only applies to the "main" Visa Waiver Program. You're entering under a separate arrangement called the Guam-CNMI Visa Waiver Program, and thus are **not** affected (and should **not** apply for an ESTA).

TIMATIC, the database used by airlines, states the following regarding mainland US (for entry under the VWP):

> Detailed information on ESTA restrictions can be found on https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/esta#

It should say "VWP restrictions", but, in any case, no reference to this is made when Guam is selected as the destination. Nor does [the DHS page about the Guam-CNI VWP](https://www.dhs.gov/guam-cnmi-visa-waiver-program) mention it at all.

That said, in order to reduce the amount of paperwork to fill out on arrival, you should register [**here**](https://i736.cbp.dhs.gov/I736/#/apply-I736) up to 7 days in advance of your arrival, and present a printed confirmation on arrival

Comment: I don't doubt the truth of the first paragraph, and I have upvoted the answer, but a source in support of the assertion that the well known VWP restrictions do not affect the Guam-CNMI VWP would improve this answer considerably.

Comment: @phoog Can't find any explicit statement, and why should there necessarily be any, seeing as the VWP and the Guam-CNMI VWP are entirely different provisions altogether?

Comment: Maybe a reference saying they are completely separate would help? Or a page listing the conditions of use of the Guam-CNMI VWP?

Comment: @Coke a TIMATIC extract that doesn't mention travel to Iran, perhaps?

Comment: @phoog It doesn't directly mention it regarding the mainland either, but I did an edit

Comment: Timatic has a separate destination for Guam (GU); you should use that instead of USA.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Exactly, and when putting that as the destination, the section I quote doesn't appear. THat's the whole point

Answer (score 2):

Timatic has this to say about visa exemptions for Australian travellers to Guam:

> Nationals of Australia, Brunei Darussalam, Japan, Korea
>     (Rep.), Malaysia, Nauru, New Zealand, Papua New Guinea,
>     Russian Fed. and Singapore traveling as tourists or on
>     business under the Guam-Northern Mariana Isl. Visa Waiver
>     program for a maximum stay of 45 days. They must have :
>
> - a machine readable passport, and
> - a signed Form I-94 (05/08), and
> - a signed Form I-736, and
> - a return/onward ticket to a country other than the USA or
>     than the neighboring islands of Guam. This does not apply to
>     residents of the USA or of the neighboring islands of Guam
>     who can have a return/onward ticket to the USA or to the
>     neighboring islands of Guam.

Though I must admit I am not sure what they mean about a signed I-94. That bit doesn't make sense.

Comment: [Visit Guam](http://www.visitguam.com/plan/entry-exit/) notes, in bold, that *I-94 customs forms are no longer being accepted* implying that only the I-736 is needed.